# How to check Audit of File on shared network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am using windows server 2008 (R2), and has a shared network. Someone make changes in a file. How can i trace that who actually do this? Please give suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can look into it using sql server management studio. 
1) expand security-> audit folder
2) right click desired log file-> view audit logs.

Comment: sql server is not install in the machine.@Arun

Comment: If its not installed, why does it have a sql server tag then..?